# Why do lsmem and free show different total memory?

Tags: centos, memory

I have a CentOS 7 machine and there's a question that bothers me.

When I use `lsmem --summary`, I get:

```
Memory block size:       128M
Total online memory:       8G
Total offline memory:      0B
```

When I use `free -h`, I get:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        850M        1.7G        361M        5.1G        6.1G
Swap:          7.7G          0B        7.7G
```

Why is the total memory I get different in the same machine?

What's the difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lsmem` lists memory blocks and their state; these reflect physical memory and are counted in units of memory blocks, *i.e.* 128MiB on your system. To do this, `lsmem` reads information made available by the kernel in `/sys/devices/system/memory`. On your system, the kernel tracks 64 memory blocks for a total of 8GiB.

`free` lists memory that’s usable by the system; “total” is the amount of physical memory, minus memory reserved by the system (for the firmware’s purposes mostly) and the kernel’s executable code. `free` reads this information from [`/proc/meminfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

The difference in output is explained by this difference in what is measured. In all cases, `free`’s total memory will be smaller than `lsmem`’s total online memory.